# Kotlin multiplatform: JobCancellationException: Parent job is Completed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I try to write a kotlin multiplatform library (android and ios) that uses ktor. Thereby I experience some issues with kotlins coroutines:

```
When writing tests I always get kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Completed; job=JobImpl{Completed}@... exception.
```

I use ktors mock engine for my tests:

```kotlin
client = HttpClient(MockEngine) 
{
    engine 
    {
         addHandler 
         { request ->
             // Create response object
         }
     }
}
```

A sample method (commonMain module) using ktor. All methods in my library are written in a similar way. The exception occures if *client.get* is called.

```kotlin
suspend fun getData(): Either<Exception, String> = coroutineScope 
{
     // Exception occurs in this line:
     val response: HttpResponse = client.get { url("https://www.google.com") }

     return if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
     {
         (response.readText() as T).right()
     } 
     else 
     {
        Exception("Error").left()
     }
}
```

A sample unit test (commonTest module) for the above method. The assertTrue statement is never called since the exception is thrown before.

```kotlin
@Test
fun getDataTest() = runTest 
{
    val result = getData()
    assertTrue(result.isRight())
}
```

Actual implementation of *runTest* in androidTest and iosTest modules.

```kotlin
actual fun<T> runTest(block: suspend () -> T) { runBlocking { block() } }
```

I thought when I use *coroutineScope*, it waits until all child coroutines are done. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this exception?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: coroutine scope, as far as i know, will cancel the others coroutines. If you want to decouple the parent job with other jobs you can use CoroutineScope.launch, or you call call with supervisor scope

Answer (score 2):

you can't cache HttpClient of CIO in client variable and reuse, It would be best if change the following code in your implementation.

```
val client:HttpClient get() = HttpClient(MockEngine) {
    engine {
         addHandler { request ->
             // Create response object
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Not clear. Give more information

Comment: The comment means, that If you store the HttpClient in a val like
val client:HttpClient get() = HttpClient(Android)

it could also lead to JobCancellationException. However if you return a new instance of the Client each time you access the value (that was the get() does), the issue goes away. At least my problem could be solved with this minor change.

Comment: @xoif this comment made it work for me, thanks for helping out. I had the same instance of the HttpClient running each time.

Answer (score 1):

The library must be updated, this glitch is in the fix report here: https://newreleases.io/project/github/ktorio/ktor/release/1.6.1

Comment: Definitely fixed it for me, coming from version 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot use the same instance of the HttpClient. My ej:

```
HttpClient(CIO) {
                install(JsonFeature) {
                    serializer = GsonSerializer()
                }
            }.use { client ->
                return@use client.request("URL") {
                    method = HttpMethod.Get
                }
            }
```