# Why tor get this error Parent job is Completed

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm using ktor for the android client but I have an error.
When I run the app for the first time everything is fine and there is no issue, but when I click on the device back button and close the app, and open it again, the app is crashed and I get this error about the ktor:

***Parent job is Completed***

this is my ktor configure the module:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object NetworkModule {

    private const val TIME_OUT = 60_000
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideKtor(): HttpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(HttpCache)
        
        defaultRequest {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(json = Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                isLenient = true
                encodeDefaults = false
            })
        }

        install(HttpTimeout) {
            connectTimeoutMillis = TIME_OUT.toLong()
            socketTimeoutMillis = TIME_OUT.toLong()
            requestTimeoutMillis = TIME_OUT.toLong()
        }

        install(ResponseObserver) {
            onResponse { response ->
                Log.d("HttpClientLogger - HTTP status", "${response.status.value}")
                Log.d("HttpClientLogger - Response:", response.toString())
            }
        }

        install(Logging) {
            logger = object : Logger {
                override fun log(message: String) {
                    Log.v("Logger Ktor =>", message)
                }

            }
            level = LogLevel.NONE
        }
    }
}
```

```
Note: I use ktor version "2.0.2".

    const val ktor_client_core = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_client_cio = "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_serialization_json = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_serialization = "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_android = "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_negotiation = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_okhttp = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"
    const val ktor_logging = "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
```

How can i fix it?

[image: stackTrace]

Comment: Could you please share a full stack trace?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman  kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Completed; job=JobImpl{Completed}@3bc957

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin multiplatform: JobCancellationException: Parent job is Completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782244/kotlin-multiplatform-jobcancellationexception-parent-job-is-completed)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: This is related to `Hilt Di (NetworkModule)`. I have to use an object instead of hilt module for now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot use the same instance of the HttpClient.

```
companion object {
    val client get() = HttpClient(Android) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing logging plugins. I was read some information about that, it caused by ktor logging issue